# differential equation with random variable - approach with Ito?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, random-variables

Assuming i have a random variable $F(t-t_1)$ for each $t-t_1$ that is distributed like $\mathcal{N}(0,f(t-t_1))$,  ($f(t-t_1)$ beeing a normal function)and i have the following differential equation:

$\dot{c}(t)=\int_0^tF(t-t_1)c(t_1)\mathrm{d}t_1$

How do I approach something like that?

Thanks already!